# How do you vote to re-open a closed question?

Tags: support

I don't see a button to cause a reopen vote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need 58 more rep (3000) to do that :-)

See your privileges list: https://ux.stackexchange.com/privileges/close-questions

Comment: Hum.  I have 2,900 Rep.   Here on Meta there is a 'close' button (under the question it says link/edit/close/delete/flag).  But on the main site there is no close button ( it just has link / edit / flag) ???

Comment: Actually  correction on that:  there's a close button on THIS THREAD in Meta.  But not on the other threads..

Comment: Well that makes sense since you asked the question :-)

Comment: Meta privileges are identical to the main site privs. The close link is always on your questions (and always shows the close vote count on your Qs), but you won't get a reopen option or close vote links on other Qs until you get the rep you need.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I didn't read Rahul's answer correctly:  So I need a rep of 3000+ to do this ?

Comment: @PhillipW Yep! Sorry if I wasn't clear.

Comment: Thanks Rahul.  Strangely I shall now have to accept the answer to my own question !

Answer (score 1):

OK, so since this Rahul's answer isn't going to make sense once my rep changes.

For anyone else coming along later the answer seems to be:

**You need a rep of 3000 (or more) to do this.**